# How do you say “How cute of you!” and “How cute!”?

Tags: constructions

Hi  I need confirmation if I’ve constructed correctly the french equivalents of **“How cute of you!”** and **“How cute!”**. Here are the following scenarios where these sentences exist.

**Scenario 1**

Person 1: I write in this font because it looks scary.

*Person 2 looks at person 1 with joy.*

Person 2. How cute of you!

**Scenario 2**

Person 1: Okay, I’ve put the dress on.

*Person 2 looks at person 1 in admiration.*

Person 2: How cute!

---

I understand that the scenarios are somewhat informal however the French constructions that I’ve come up with are formal only because I would like to know how to write these sentences formally.

---

For the sentence “How cute of you!”, is the french equivalent

1. **« Que mignon(ne) de toi ! »**

or

2. **« Que tu es mignon(ne) ! »**

or

3. **« Que c’est mignon(ne) de ta part ! »** ?

I think it’s the latter (1) and/or (3).

Lastly, for the sentence “How cute!”, is the french equivalent **« Que mignon(ne) ! »**?

If this is correct, **does the sentence “How very cute!” equal « Que très mignon(ne) ! »**?

Comment: Done! Thank you for this @20goto10 ! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically incorrect, so is *Que très mignon !*

The second sentence means "How pretty you are!".

The third sentence is right assuming "cute" means *sweet, lovely*. Otherwise, if "cute" means "clever" see [20goto10's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44061/1109).

Alternatively, you can also say:

> *Comme c'est mignon de ta part !*

so "How cute!" can be translated to *Comme c'est mignon !* or *Comme c'est chou/adorable/charmant !*.

Note that in that meaning, *mignon* is always masculine. What is cute is something (*ce*), not someone.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help @jlliagre !  I’m a bit confused by your last sentence: So it’s always *« que/comme c’est **mignon** de ta part ! »* and never *« que/comme c’est **mignonne** de ta part ! »*? Also, how do you say “How very cute!”?

Comment: Person 1: He gave me a rose  and chocolates for Valentines Day and we walked home together while holding hands.

Comment: Person 2: How very cute!!!

Comment: Yes, It's never *comme c'est mignonne* if only because *ce* doesn't represent a person but a thing and the "neutral" pronoun *ce* is always masculine. "How very cute!!!" → *Comme c'est super mignon !!!*

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you ! 

Answer (score 2):

The first scenario with *how cute of you* has nothing to do with appearance but rather with [appealing cleverness](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/cute). The adjective [*malin*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/malin#Adjectif) (to mean *fin, rusé, astucieux, finaud, futé*) [can be leveraged](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/cute/573749) here :

> C'est bien malin/fin/rusé/astucieux/finaud/futé (de ta part) !

I prefer relying on [*bien*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien) to create the degree here instead of [*comme*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme) (*combien, à quel point*).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this meaning of "cute".